# Django app names are not translated in CMS

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, translation

I have a Django application in which I'm willing to translate app names appearing in Django CMS.

[Models are translated but not app names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Up7.png)

As i have searched i found that i have to add verbose_name to AppConfig class in apps.py for each app i add to application:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'core'
    verbose_name = _("core")
```

but it does not change anything in cms after i makemessage and compilemessage it.

Even if i delete this class nothing changes, framework doesn't yield

Django Version: 2.0.3

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
/yourappname/apps.py:
      class ServicesConfig(AppConfig):
          name = 'services'
          verbose_name = 'Translated text'
```

More info? check this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

I have these config on a localhost project, i only change the text and works, look that
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit late but:

Use normal translation in the verbose_name field in your config:

core/apps.py
[image: core/apps.py]

Then, in your settings specify the config file to use in your app:

[image: config file to use in your app]

**Warning!** If in settings you only specify app name ('core') it will use a default config and therefore, bypass your translation.

Then just configure the .po file as you already know.